# Version History of list item

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom

Is there a way to capture the previous version history of list items (probably based on the version number) using CSOM?

Comment: I haven't used CSOM but there is in JSOM. Looks like maybe this is the equivalent CSOM page to view? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.versions.aspx

Answer (score 3):

In SharePoint 2013 on premise, we cannot get the version history by CSOM. CSOM does not provide such API.

As a workaround, we can use the SharePoint web service.

For more detailed information, you could refer to the post below.

There is a similar post:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/177ceafb-debd-4020-b943-904c220cbf5f/how-to-get-list-item-versions-using-csom?forum=appsforsharepoint

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in SharePoint Online via the CSOM, if you have later than the September 2017 version.

Each `ListItem` will have a `Versions` property, which is of type `ListItemVersionCollection`. If you loop through these versions each ListItemVersion inside will have a `FieldValues` and you can fetch your data from these.

```
 foreach (var version in item.Versions)
 {                        
       string versionLabel = version.VersionLabel;
       string versiondate = version.FieldValues["Modified"].ToString();
       string AssignedTo = ((FieldUserValue)version["AssignedTo"])?.LookupValue ?? "";                       
 }
```

https://dev.office.com/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365-september-2017